# loop parameter pack lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I have a small bit of code.

I want to know if i could cut out my ProcessArg function

I would like to loop the parameter pack from inside my call function.

Im i best to use a lambda function in initializer_list or something else, if so how do i do it.

Thanks

```
template <class R, class Arg>
R ProcessArg(Arg&& arg) {
    std::cout << typeid(arg).name() << (std::is_reference<Arg>::value ? "&" : "") << std::endl;
    //std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_reference<Arg>::value << std::endl; // not always true
    return R();
}

template <typename R, typename... Args>
R CallFunction(Args&&... args) {
    std::size_t size = sizeof...(Args);
    std::initializer_list<R>{ProcessArg<R>(std::forward<Args>(args)) ...};
    return R();
}

template<typename Fn> class FunctionBase;
template<typename R, typename... Args>
class FunctionBase <R(*)(Args...)> {
public:
    FunctionBase() {}
    R operator()(Args&&... args) { // Args&& is a universal reference
        return CallFunction<R>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

int foo(int a, int& b) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_reference<decltype(a)>::value << std::endl; // falae
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_reference<decltype(b)>::value << std::endl; // true
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    int in = 10;
    foo(1, in);

    FunctionBase<decltype(&foo)> func;
    func(1, in);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) fold-expressions, you can replace:

```
std::initializer_list<R>{ProcessArg<R>(std::forward<Args>(args)) ...};
```

with:

```
((std::cout << typeid(args).name()
            << (std::is_reference<Args>::value ? "&" : "")
            << std::endl
 ), ...);
```

Or with a lambda expression to improve readability:

```
auto process = [](auto&& arg) {
    std::cout << typeid(arg).name()
              << (std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(arg)>::value ? "&" : "")
              << std::endl;
};

(process(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
```

---

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20):

```
auto process = [] <typename Arg> (Arg&& arg) {
    std::cout << typeid(arg).name()
              << (std::is_reference<Arg>::value ? "&" : "")
              << std::endl;
};

(process(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
```

Comment: When i try the last example both my arguments are returning true from `is_reference`

Comment: @docasok733 use `std::is_lvalue_reference` instead then, or C++20 version

Comment: Do you know how i could reverse the order of the lambda so it loops from last arg to 1st arg?

Comment: @docasok733 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc7f5035f22752d0

Comment: Thank you, that was fast, your the best +rep

Comment: I have really simple question for you, in the process lambda i am doing `count++` to get the current argument index number, is there a simple way to add that to the lambda so i dont have to define size_t out side lambda and then use count++?

Comment: @docasok733 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a8e0393c63a891e